# Zend Server and ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, iis, zend-server-ce

I've installed Zend Server, and it works well - it's on localhost, port 81, with the admin interface/phpmyadmin on port 10081.

I'm not really sure how to get it working with ASP.NET as well as PHP, if that's possible.
How would you configure this with IIS.

I should add, I also have an *existing* Apache install on port 80 using Web-Developer Server Suite downloaded from sourceforge.net; should I move everything over to the Zend one, then change the Apache config to port 80, uninstall the old Apache?

As for aspx files, can they be run on Zend within the install (my directory for it's C:/websites1/, the Apache files residing in Apache2/htdocs in this directory), but where would you put IIS files and how would you be able to run both Apache and ASP.NET on port 80 in this - modaspdotnet?

Not sure what's the best way to do this, so advice is appreciated.

Comment: this is a not suggested thing to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not run simultaneously two HTTP server on same port (Indeed there is no point in doing that).
I recommend continue using multiple port, it will work seamlessly.